# Can HORNET be implemented into Tor?

Tags: protocol

A while ago a group of researchers presented a Tor like network called [HORNET](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05724v1.pdf); it is, reportedly, ["a better, faster Tor"](http://arstechnica.co.uk/information-technology/2015/07/researchers-claim-theyve-developed-a-better-faster-tor/). Do you know if the improvements proposed in the paper could be incrementally implemented in the Tor architecture? Or is there some fundamental difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some fundamental difference between the two?

AFAIK, the fundamental difference is that Tor works in the TCP layer and HORNET works in the Network layer. So, implementing HORNET in Tor may not be the best option.

There are some interesting discussions around this topic in the internet, but there seems to be no 'official' response from Tor on what they think about HORNET. If you look closely, in general, the opinion is in favor of Tor because of a number of reasons.

There is a high-level take on HORNET by [Gibson](https://www.grc.com/sn/sn-518.htm) that's worth a read. [This](https://www.mail-archive.com/tor-talk@lists.torproject.org/msg18757.html) mailing list and [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/3fe4jc/tor_vs_hornet/) also discuss the issues.

Comment: Thank you, the mailing list discussion kind of answers my question: https://www.mail-archive.com/tor-talk@lists.torproject.org/msg18763.html

Comment: @muzzle why was this answer unaccepted after so many months? Did I miss anything in my post?

Comment: please exuse my fat fingers, I must have unaccepted it by mistake :)